# Megaspherulite growth

Tags: geology, rocks

I have been fascinated by photos of these for a while, and I would like to ask how megaspherulites grow so large, when spherulites are normally quite small?

I also noticed that all papers about the formation of megaspherulites I could find (such as [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23822404_Growth_of_Megaspherulites_In_a_Rhyolitic_Vitrophyre) one) seem to say that they form in rhyolitic vitrophyre.

Why do they only form in rhyolitic vitrophyre?

[image: megaspherulite photo]

Comment: Another paper of interest about this matter: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00445-020-01382-8